# Empty file saved after stream object write line command

Tags: c#

on the  below code I read a file line by line and try to save the read lines in another file.
If I display the read lines in the console, it shows the correct content of the read file (test1.txt). But when I check the content of saved file (test2.txt) it is empty.
I tried many other codes and the result is the same. I do not know what is wrong. Can anyone help me? Thanks.
test1.txt  content = (four lines)
1
2
3
4

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace texto
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int counter = 0;
        string line;

        // Read the file and display it line by line.  
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new 
           System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\Dados\test1.txt");
        System.IO.StreamWriter file1 = new 
             System.IO.StreamWriter(@"c:\Dados\test2.txt");


        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            counter++;

            //string file3 = line.Substring(0, (23));
            file1.WriteLine(line + " " + counter);

        }

        file.Close();
        System.Console.WriteLine("There were {0} lines.", counter);
        // Suspend the screen.  
        System.Console.ReadLine(); 

    }


}
   }
```

Comment: Check your stream, move to position 0 before write.

Comment: Where is the code? edit your question and add the code please

Comment: Close `file1` or do `Flush`

Comment: As a note, try and pick better names. `inputFile` and `outputFile` as opposed to `file` and `file1`,

Comment: Using `using` is useful. If duplicate does not explain it enough - make sure to search https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+write+text+file and then [edit] questions clarifying why it was enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mahmound. It worked closing the file1.